# How to create a python exception with multiple causes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception

How do I raise a python exception with multiple causes, similar to Java's [addSuppressed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) feature? For example I have list of multiple methods to try and if none of them work I want to raise an exception that includes the exceptions from all the methods that were tried. I.e.:

```py
exceptions = []
for method in methods_to_try:
  try:
    method()
  except Exception as e:
    exceptions.append(e)
if exceptions:
  raise Exception("All methods failed") from exceptions
```

But this code fails because the `raise ... from ...` statement expects a single exception and not a list. Python 2 or 3 solutions are acceptable. All back traces and exception messages must be preserved.

Comment: you cannot raise _several_ exceptions. Create a big exception with all the stacktraces and raise this. This is going to be ugly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the exceptions as arguments when creating the last exception.

```
for method in methods_to_try:
    try:
        method()
    except Exception as e:
        exceptions.append(e)
if exceptions:
    raise Exception(*exceptions)
```

They will be available en the `args` attribute.

Comment: I still only see the traceback from the last exception raised. I'm looking for a solution that preserves all the tracebacks.

Comment: @Evan The tracebacks are inside the exceptions, if you want to print them you need to write the code. AFAIK the default python handling can't do what you want. Look at the module [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) for help.

Comment: Only python 3 exceptions have `__traceback__`. On python 2 you can use `sys.exc_info` to store the traceback before appending the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Once could raise each exception from the other to chain it. The only issue is with the cause order which may be misleading.

```
def combine_exc(exceptions):
   c_exc = None
   for ex in reversed(exceptions):
      try:
         if c_exc is None:
            raise ex
         else:
            raise ex from c_exc
      except Exception as ex1:
         c_exc = ex1

   return c_exc
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use logging instead

If using the logging module is acceptable for you, I guess it would be the cleanest to log the individual exceptions you caught and only raise a single overall exception.

If you only want to output the log-messages in case all tried functions error, this is an ideal case for the buffered logger from the  [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#buffering-logging-messages-and-outputting-them-conditionally)
You could modify it to always log at debug level, but raise the level to error, if all subfunctions raise an error.

Comment: Logging creates unwanted side effects for the code. I'm looking for a way to preserve multiple exceptions/tracebacks in a single raised exception.